# Fetching Oracle DB LONG type through jdbc works very slow

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

This happens only when the statement return *LONG* column.
Even if i don't do anything with it such like *rs.getString*, just execute.

> **sql1: That was: 7593 ms 
>  sql2: That was: 530 ms**

As you can see it's not about volume of data.
When i use **OracleConnection:OracleStatement:OracleCachedResultSet** result is the same.
Also i tried to use **OracleCachedRowSet** instead of **ResultSet**.
Problem shows up in **OracleCachedRowSet.execute()** before **OracleCachedRowSet.next()**.
When i set **setFetchSize(1)**:

> **sql1: That was: 7474 ms 
>  sql2: That was: 7153 ms**

**UPDATE 1:** 
I had tested other tools:

> **sql1#** Toad For Oracle : execution time < 1 second
>   **sql1#** Oracle SQL Developer thin: 7.5 second(same as my result)
>   **sql1#** Oracle SQL Developer OCI: 7.5 second(same as my result)
>   **sql2#** Oracle SQL Developer thin: 0.36 second(same as my result)
>   Rows fethed one by one in sql1 case in java app, so look like setFetchSize() dosn't work.

Sample code:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

        final String sql1 = "select HIGH_VALUE from sys.DBA_TAB_PARTITIONS WHERE rownum < 20";
        final String sql2 = "select PARTITION_NAME, HIGH_VALUE_LENGTH,TABLESPACE_NAME,NUM_ROWS,BLOCKS,\n"
                + "EMPTY_BLOCKS,LAST_ANALYZED,AVG_SPACE,SUBPARTITION_COUNT,COMPRESSION from sys.DBA_TAB_PARTITIONS WHERE rownum < 20";

        OracleDataSource ods = new OracleDataSource();
        ods.setDriverType("thin");
        ods.setUser("vr");
        ods.setPassword("oracle");
        ods.setDatabaseName("ORCL");
        ods.setServerName("192.172.18.1");
        ods.setPortNumber(1521);

        Connection conn = null;
        conn = ods.getConnection();

        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        stmt.setFetchSize(1000);

        // Start time
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql1);
        rs.setFetchSize(1000);
        while (rs.next()){
            //System.out.println(rs.getString(1) + " " +  rs.getString(2));
            System.out.println("row#: " + rs.getRow());
        }

        // Finish time        
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("That was: " + (endTime - startTime) + " ms");
    } 
}
```

Comment: so how long does it take if you run it from a DB client?  Have you tried explain plan?

Comment: When i execute it from Toad it gives me result in the moment. I think it's not about plan, because the data should be cached after i execute the statement hundred of times. But i i've got idea now. I am gonna try it with Oracle SQL Developer, because it uses the same driver and i will update my post. Thank you.

Comment: @Scary Wombat 
Seems to be bug. Native Oracle SQL Developer have the same issue. It means that there is no more option than casting it to **VARCHAR2** on the database side.

Comment: Isn't `LONG` a deprecated datatype? You might want to check if you get better performance when using a `BLOB` instead.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel True, but i am working with oracle internal tables/views as in my example **DBA_TAB_PARTITIONS**. And at least up to 11gR2 they still using LONG. Look like i found some workaround with new ojdbc7.jar driver, so if its true i will answer my question soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Results with new **ojdbc7.jar**(before i used **ojdbc6.jar** from 11.2.0.2 bundle) and **OracleJDBCRowSet**.
19 rows:

> **sql1 : That was: 1470 ms  // before 7-8 seconds**
>   **sql2 : That was: 1140 ms**

99 rows:

> **sql1 : That was: 1491 ms**
>   **sql2 : That was: 1158 ms**

As you can see its much faster, but still slower than query with even much more data.
Adding more column almost make no changes in execution and fetching time, so the problem partially solved.
But seems that the improvements comes to RowSets only.
**OracleResultSet** still work extremly slow.
Also if you link new driver with **Oracle SQL Developer** it takes no effect.

Sample code:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String sql1 = "select HIGH_VALUE from sys.DBA_TAB_PARTITIONS WHERE rownum < 100";
        final String sql2 = "select PARTITION_NAME, HIGH_VALUE_LENGTH,TABLESPACE_NAME,NUM_ROWS,BLOCKS,\n"
                + "EMPTY_BLOCKS,LAST_ANALYZED,AVG_SPACE,SUBPARTITION_COUNT,COMPRESSION "
                + "from sys.DBA_TAB_PARTITIONS WHERE rownum < 100";

        OracleDataSource ods = null;
        try {
            ods = new OracleDataSource();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.exit(2);
        }
        ods.setDriverType("thin");
        ods.setUser("vr");
        ods.setPassword("oracle");
        ods.setDatabaseName("ORCL");
        ods.setServerName("192.172.18.1");
        ods.setPortNumber(1521);

        try (Connection conn = ods.getConnection();) {
            try (OracleJDBCRowSet rs = new OracleJDBCRowSet(conn);) {
                rs.setFetchSize(200);
                rs.setReadOnly(true);
                rs.setCommand(sql2);

                // Start time
                long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                rs.execute();
                while (rs.next()) {
                        System.out.println("row#: " + rs.getRow() + " " + rs.getString(1));
                }

                // Finish time        
                long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                System.out.println("That was: " + (endTime - startTime) + " ms");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One issue might be data dictionary tables are slow in some versions of oracle. I use this below optimizer function in java and dramatically improves performance of DBA table queries (no idea what it does just took from oracles support site). Long types are still very slow however and Im still looking for a solution to that issue. For instance DBA_TAB_COLS.DATA_DEFAULT is a Long and that adds 6 minutes to my query. If I remove that column it goes from 6 minutes to 30 seconds. I am looking at trying to cast to string before returning in result set since all the values in my DB are less that 1000 characters.

private static void optimize(Connection con) {

```
try {
    String OPT = "alter session set \"_optimizer_cbqt_or_expansion\"=OFF";
    con.prepareStatement(OPT).execute();
}
catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}